# Android TabLayout With Swipeable Views Button Click From One Fragment To Another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, swipe

I am following this tutorial: [androidhive - tab layout with swipe able views](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/). I would like to have a button on the first tab fragment and link it over to the second tab fragment. may i have some guide on how to go about doing this? all the fragments have different layouts.

I am currently using this method in the first tab fragment, it works!

```
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((mainActivity)getActivity()).viewPager.setCurrentItem(2); //position of tab3 = 2
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when user presses the button you can set the current fragment to be the 2nd fragment by using the `viewPagerReference.setCurrentItem(theItemThatYouWishToShowInYourFragments)`

Comment: But the button is in first fragment tab. and where do this piece of code goes to?

Comment: its in the first fragment right? so you set listener on button in first fragment.

Comment: but the activity is using an adapter. and all the fragments have different layouts and different logics. :/

Comment: you are setting the adapter for the viewpager only.

Comment: I have set the listener on button in the first fragment. but how am i going to add "viewPagerReference.setCurrentItem(theItemThatYouWishToShowInYourFragments)"?

Comment: in the listener method

Comment: yeah but how do i reference the viewPager?

Comment: make the reference of the viewPager globally accessible

Comment: can you post your code? where have you written the code for the fragments in separate file or in your MainActivity?

Comment: It was my mistake. Overlooked at the wrong code! Sorry! Thank you for you help!

Comment: Another question if possible, how do I refresh/restart all the tab fragments when they are selected/reselected? Or do I start and ask another question?

Comment: start another question

Answer (score 1):

I have used Tablayout inside a fragment(parent class is Fragment that has inner fragments). Switch between the fragment below is the code where tab_layout is the id of the TabLayout and getTabAt(integer) , here integer is the tab's index number where you want to move. For information tabs maintain index number from zero.

```
TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
            tabs.getTabAt(0).select();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Tara's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39698581/1363087):

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TabLayout tabs = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
            int iNewPosition = oTabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() + 1;
            tabs.getTabAt(iNewPosition).select();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial out from the official android developers channel that teaches  you to make   a sliding tab layout like google play and then you can add the code to the button click.
Check it out

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRg_eDfQ8fk

Answer (score 0):

To swipe from one tab to another tab we can simply do:

```
tablayout.getTabAt(0).select();
```

where tablayout is tablayout view
and 0 is the position of tab where you want to move.